# Erro JSF: javax.el.PropertyNotWritableException

Tags: java, jsf, java-ee, jsf-2.2, java-8

Estou com um erro que não consigo resolver e não sei o motivo Segue erro e minhas classes e view abaixo.

```
type Exception report

messageInternal Server Error

descriptionThe server encountered an internal error that prevented it from fulfilling this request.

exception

javax.servlet.ServletException: javax.el.PropertyNotWritableException: /novo-empregado.xhtml @90,162 value="#{empregadoController.empregado.matricula}": The class 'br.com.loogix.model.Empregado' does not have a writable property 'matricula'.

root cause

javax.faces.component.UpdateModelException: javax.el.PropertyNotWritableException: /novo-empregado.xhtml @90,162 value="#{empregadoController.empregado.matricula}": The class 'br.com.loogix.model.Empregado' does not have a writable property 'matricula'.

root cause

javax.el.PropertyNotWritableException: /novo-empregado.xhtml @90,162 value="#{empregadoController.empregado.matricula}": The class 'br.com.loogix.model.Empregado' does not have a writable property 'matricula'.

root cause

javax.el.PropertyNotWritableException: The class 'br.com.loogix.model.Empregado' does not have a writable property 'matricula'.
```

classe **EmpregadoController.java**

```
/*
 * To change this license header, choose License Headers in Project Properties.
 * To change this template file, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */
package br.com.loogix.controller;

import br.com.loogix.dao.AlmoxarifadoDAO;
import br.com.loogix.dao.EmpregadoDAO;
import br.com.loogix.dao.FuncaoDAO;
import br.com.loogix.model.Almoxarifado;
import br.com.loogix.model.Empregado;
import br.com.loogix.model.Funcao;
import javax.inject.Named;
import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.List;
import javax.ejb.EJB;
import javax.enterprise.context.SessionScoped;

/**
 *
 * @author thiago
 */
@Named(value = "empregadoController")
@SessionScoped
public class EmpregadoController implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @EJB
    private EmpregadoDAO daoEmpregado;

    @EJB
    private FuncaoDAO daoFuncao;

    @EJB
    private AlmoxarifadoDAO almoxarifadoDAO;

    private Empregado empregado;
    private List<Empregado> empregados;
    private boolean alterando = false;
    private Long idFuncaoEmpregado;
    private Long idAlmoxarifadoEmpregado;

    public String listar() {
        this.empregados = this.daoEmpregado.getList();
        return "empregado?faces-redirect=true";
    }

    public String novo() {
        this.idFuncaoEmpregado = null;
        this.empregado = new Empregado();
        this.alterando = false;
        return "novo-empregado?faces-redirect=true";
    }

    public String iniciarAlterar(Empregado empregado) {
        this.empregado = empregado;
        this.alterando = true;
        return "novo-empregado?faces-redirect=true";
    }


    public String gravar() {

        Funcao funcao = this.daoFuncao.buscaPorId(this.idFuncaoEmpregado);
        this.empregado.setFuncao(funcao);

        Almoxarifado almoxarifado = this.almoxarifadoDAO.buscaPorId(this.idAlmoxarifadoEmpregado);
        this.empregado.setAlmoxarifado(almoxarifado);

        if (this.alterando == false)
            this.daoEmpregado.add(this.empregado);
        else
            this.daoEmpregado.update(this.empregado);

        this.empregados = this.daoEmpregado.getList();

        return "empregado?faces-redirect=true"; 
    }

    public String excluir(Empregado empregado) {
        this.daoEmpregado.delete(empregado);
        this.empregados = this.daoEmpregado.getList();
        return null;
    }

    public Empregado getEmpregado() {
        return empregado;
    }

    public void setEmpregado(Empregado empregado) {
        this.empregado = empregado;
    }

    public List<Empregado> getEmpregados() {
        return this.daoEmpregado.getList();
    }

    public List<Funcao> getFuncoes() {
        return this.daoFuncao.getList();
    }

    public Long getFuncaoEmpregado() {
        return idFuncaoEmpregado;
    }

    public void setFuncaoEmpregado(Long id) {
        idFuncaoEmpregado = id;
    }

    public Long getAlmoxarifadoEmpregado() {
        return idAlmoxarifadoEmpregado;
    }

    public void setAlmoxarifadoEmpregado(Long idAlmoxarifadoEmpregado) {
        this.idAlmoxarifadoEmpregado = idAlmoxarifadoEmpregado;
    }

    public List<Almoxarifado> getAlmoxarifados() {
        return this.almoxarifadoDAO.getList();
    }

}
```

Modelo **Empregado.java**

```
/*
 * To change this license header, choose License Headers in Project Properties.
 * To change this template file, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */
package br.com.loogix.model;

import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Objects;
import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.JoinColumn;
import javax.persistence.ManyToOne;
import javax.persistence.OneToMany;
import javax.persistence.Table;

/**
 *
 * @author thiago
 */
@Entity
@Table (name = "empregado")
public class Empregado implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    @Column(name = "matricula", nullable = false)
    private String matricula;

    private String nome;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn (name = "id_funcao")
    private Funcao funcao;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "id_almoxarifado")
    private Almoxarifado almoxarifado;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "empregado")
    private List<Saida> saidas;

    public Empregado() {
    }

    public Empregado(Long id, String matricula, String nome, Funcao funcao, Almoxarifado almoxarifado, List<Saida> saidas) {
        this.id = id;
        this.matricula = matricula;
        this.nome = nome;
        this.funcao = funcao;
        this.almoxarifado = almoxarifado;
        this.saidas = saidas;
    }

    public String getNome() {
        return nome;
    }

    public void setNome(String nome) {
        this.nome = nome;
    }

    public Funcao getFuncao() {
        return funcao;
    }

    public void setFuncao(Funcao funcao) {
        this.funcao = funcao;
    }

    public String getMatricula() {
        return matricula;
    }

    public Almoxarifado getAlmoxarifado() {
        return almoxarifado;
    }

    public void setAlmoxarifado(Almoxarifado almoxarifado) {
        this.almoxarifado = almoxarifado;
    }

    public List<Saida> getSaidas() {
        return Collections.unmodifiableList(saidas);
    }

    public void addSaida(Saida saida) {
        this.saidas.add(saida);
        saida.setEmpregado(this);
    }

    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        int hash = 7;
        hash = 83 * hash + Objects.hashCode(this.id);
        return hash;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object obj) {
        if (obj == null) {
            return false;
        }
        if (getClass() != obj.getClass()) {
            return false;
        }
        final Empregado other = (Empregado) obj;
        if (!Objects.equals(this.id, other.id)) {
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }

}
```

Meu DAO **EmpregadoDAO.java**

```
/*
 * To change this license header, choose License Headers in Project Properties.
 * To change this template file, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */
package br.com.loogix.dao;

import br.com.loogix.model.Empregado;
import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.List;
import javax.annotation.PostConstruct;
import javax.ejb.Stateless;
import javax.persistence.EntityManager;
import javax.persistence.PersistenceContext;
import javax.persistence.Query;

/**
 *
 * @author thiago
 */
@Stateless
public class EmpregadoDAO implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    private GenericDAO<Empregado> dao;

    @PersistenceContext
    EntityManager em;

    @PostConstruct
    public void init() {
        this.dao = new GenericDAO<Empregado>(this.em);
    }

    public void add(Empregado empregado) {
       this.dao.add(empregado);
    }

    public void update(Empregado empregado) {
        this.dao.update(empregado);
    }

    public void delete(Empregado empregado) {
        empregado = this.em.merge(empregado);
        this.dao.delete(empregado);
    }

    public List<Empregado> getList() {
        Query q = em.createQuery("select e from Empregado e");
        return q.getResultList();
    }

}
```

Meu formulário em minha view: **empregado.xhtml**

```
<h:form>

  <div class="clearfix m-t-3">
    <h:outputLabel for="matricula" value="Matricula" rendered="false"/>
    <h:inputText value="#{empregadoController.empregado.matricula}" id="matricula" pt:placeholder="Digite a matricula do empregado"/>
  </div>

  <div class="clearfix m-t-1">
    <h:outputLabel for="nome" value="Nome:" rendered="false"/>
    <h:inputText value="#{empregadoController.empregado.nome}" id="nome" class="form-control" required="true" pt:placeholder="Digite o nome do empregado"/>
  </div>

  <div class="clearfix m-t-1">
    <h:outputLabel for="funcao" value="Função" rendered="false"/>
    <h:selectOneMenu id="funcao" value="#{empregadoController.funcaoEmpregado}" class="form-control custom-select">
      <f:selectItem itemLabel="Selecionar uma função" itemValue="#{null}" />
      <f:selectItems value="#{empregadoController.funcoes}" var="funcao" itemLabel="#{funcao.nome}" itemValue="#{funcao.id}" />
    </h:selectOneMenu>
  </div>

  <div class="clearfix m-t-1">
    <h:outputLabel for="almoxarifado" value="Almoxarifado" rendered="false"/>
    <h:selectOneMenu id="almoxarifado" value="#{empregadoController.almoxarifadoEmpregado}" class="form-control custom-select">
      <f:selectItem itemLabel="Selecionar o número do almoxarifado" itemValue="#{null}" />
      <f:selectItems value="#{empregadoController.almoxarifados}" var="almoxarifado" itemLabel="#{almoxarifado.numero}" itemValue="#{almoxarifado.id}" />
    </h:selectOneMenu>
  </div>

  <div class="clearfix m-t-1">
    <h:commandButton action="#{empregadoController.gravar()}" value="Gravar empregado" class="btn btn-success form-control" />
  </div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Esse erro é da expression language do jsp, [link](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/bnahu.html).

Ele ocorre porque na sua classe `Empregado` não tem o método `setMatricula()` por isso a exception **javax.el.PropertyNotWritableException**.

Comment: Obrigado! Isso mesmo!